# X-ray unit analysis

Tags: x-rays

A survey meter is used to measure X-ray scatter radiation coming through a wall from an adjacent X-ray room.  During the test X-ray pulse, the survey meter simultaneously meassures the “accumulated dose” in uGy and the “average dose rate” in uGy/s. To find the actual “exposure time” in seconds, is it correct to devide the “accumulated dose” by the “average dose rate”?
Thanks

Comment: yes (characters to fill length limit)

Comment: I would not rely on that being a particularly accurate measurement of the length of a pulse though.

Comment: Welcome Roadschollar50 to Physics Stack Exchange.  Someone might be able to help, but they'd likely need the question to answer at least some of the following questions: What is the meter make/model? Have you read its manual? What is its Response Time? What is its averaging time? How does it calculate the average dose rate, i.e. does it only count time above some threshold count rate? Is the X-ray pulse too short to time with a stopwatch? What is the make/model of the x-ray source? Have you read its manual?  Why do you want to know the "exposure time"? Is it to estimate the X-ray pulse length?